# Repo sync in android sample source code

Tags: android, repository, ubuntu-12.04

When I am doing Repo sync in terminal in Ubuntu it give the error

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0.
```

The terminal output is:

```
aashutosh@toslap01:/media/development/platform/Android/source_code$
repo --trace sync -l : unpickle
/media/development/platform/Android/source_code/.repo/manifests.git/config
: git config --file /home/aashutosh/.gitconfig --null --list 1>| 2>|

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/media/development/platform/Android/source_code/.repo/repo/main.py",
line 385, in 

<module>
_Main(sys.argv[1:])    File "/media/development/platform/Android/source_code/.repo/repo/main.py",
line 365, in _Main

result = repo._Run(argv) or 0   File "/media/development/platform/Android/source_code/.repo/repo/main.py",
line 121, in _Run

copts, cargs = cmd.OptionParser.parse_args(argv)   File "/media/development/platform/Android/source_code/.repo/repo/command.p
line 45, in OptionParser

self._Options(self._optparse)   File "/media/development/platform/Android/source_code/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py",
line 126, in _Options

self.jobs = self.manifest.default.sync_j   File "/media/development/platform/Android/source_code/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py",
line 245, in default
self._Load()   File "/media/development/platform/Android/source_code/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py",
line 287, in _Load

self.manifestProject.worktree))   File "/media/development/platform/Android/source_code/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py",
line 302, in _ParseManifestXml

root = xml.dom.minidom.parse(path)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1920, in parse
return expatbuilder.parse(file)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 924, in
parse
result = builder.parseFile(fp)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in
parseFile
 parser.Parse(buffer, 0)

xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```